# Group replacement with re sub in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a text file where I need to replace few words.
File content is

```
user "username"
password "P@ssword"
dbname "SOME_DB_NAME"
```

I'm trying this

```
r = re.compile('{}\s"([\w@#$%^&*]+)"'.format('password'))
r.sub('new_passw0rd', file)
```

In the result re.sub replaces all symbols which is matched by regexp how to replace only matched group?

Comment: Capture what you need to keep and use backreferences in the replacement pattern. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V9qCBT/2). Are you looking for this result, `"P@ssword" password`?

Comment: `r.sub('password "new_passw0rd"', file)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm looking for this result: 
    password "new_passw0rd"

Comment: Then you do not even need a group here.

Comment: And the main question is **How to replace a particular group?**

Comment: See my first comment - you just do not use a backreference to it. Capture all the rest.

Comment: Ok, thanks I will try

Comment: There is a way to replace just a capturing group contents, but the code will look rather messy.

Comment: Did my answer work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

Regex matches some string of text, and there is a capturing mechanism that lets store submatches  that one can refer to/reuse later, after a match is found.

So, capture what you need to keep and match the rest. In your case, you need to keep `password`, whitespaces and `"` around the new password.

Use

```
import re

s = """
user "username"
password "P@ssword"
dbname "SOME_DB_NAME"
"""
r = re.compile(r'({}\s")[\w@#$%^&*]+"'.format('password'))
print(r.sub(r'\1new_passw0rd"', s))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/3j3Wu8).

Output:

```
user "username"
password "new_passw0rd"
dbname "SOME_DB_NAME"
```

Here, `(password\s")` matches and capture `password`+a whitespace+`"` into Group 1 (that is later referred to with `\1` backreference - pay attention to the `r''` raw string declaration) and `[\w@#$%^&*]+"` only matches 1+ word and some special chars followed with `"` (that can be also captured, but I just used a `"` in the replacement to put it back into the result).